# What is "$f$" in deuterium-hydrogen ratio measurements?

Tags: hydrogen, isotopes

On D-H ratio plots, $f$ seems to be used as a reference point, e.g. on the right axis in this plot of D/H ratios around the solar system from [a 67/P paper](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/347/6220/1261952.abstract):

[image]

What exactly is $f$ and how is it defined?

Answer (score 1):

The ratio of $D/H$ for Sun is defined as $f=1$.  An increase of $D/H$ ratio by a factor of $10$ is $f=10$.  You can get this by dividing the actual $D/H$ ratio on the left hand side by the $D/H$ number for the Sun.

For example, the $(D/H)_\mathrm{67P}$ is between $20$ and $30$ times the ratio that it is for the Sun or approximately  $(D/H)_\mathrm{67P} \sim 5\times 10^{-4}$ vs. $(D/H)_\mathrm{Sun} \sim 2\cdot 10^{-5}$ 
$$
f\sim (5\cdot 10^{-4})/(2\cdot 10^{-5})  =25
$$

Answer (score -1):

I guess f is deuterium enrichment factor (http://perso.utinam.cnrs.fr/~mousis/papier25.pdf )

EDIT: there is a definition of D enrichment factor in http://www.lpi.usra.edu/books/MESSII/9038.pdf (page 341)

Comment: I saw that, but it offers no clues about how that ratio was defined. "The solar nebula" seems like a fairly abstract concept that cannot be measured directly nowadays. What's the method to infer back 4.5 billion years?

Comment: Also, a link to a PDF (with no excerpt) is not recommended for answers as it's more than likely that link will rot.